# File keeps returning in Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a Drupal environment using Docker containers. 
To achieve this I created 2 docker containers. 
one for drupal itself and the other for a MariaDB instance.
Those are bundled using docker-compose:

[image]

The goal of this environment is to test existing websites against PHP 7.x.
To do this I need to import a DB dump with settings.php (credentials) file.

Everything worked fine until yesterdag.

Every time I launch the docker-compose file and dive into it using:

```
 docker exec -it drupal_environment bash
```

An old settings.php file keeps returning. 
I already deleted my volumes, images, networks and (running) containers.

settings.php:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Still having the same problem, even if I pull the images freshly from the docker hub.

Comment: this sounds like a modified image without a commit, so launching the "old" image. Something like `docker run...` then modify a file with `docker exec -it ...`, if you do not `docker commit container_name_or_id new_image` and launch the new_image, you still get the old value in your file

Comment: I assume you build locally your image outside of compose?

Comment: Nowpe, images are being build inside compose

Comment: But I don't see and build in your yaml? Did you remove before posting?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Found the solution.
Since I mount my whole site directory into the docker container

```
- ../:/var/www/html
```

the settings.php file that was set the first time keeps returning from host.